# What species left these underwater eggs?

Tags: species-identification, eggs, limnology

While inspecting some plants planted about 1.5 ft underwater in my pond, I noticed what appeared to be eggs on many of the plants.

Note that the eggs are the white, oblong, opaque things. The clear perfect spheres in the picture are just water bubbles.

For scale, the branch is probably 1/8" thick. These are really tiny, maybe 1 mm across.

The location is the American southwest.

The eggs had to be at least 1 ft underwater, which rules out most kinds of flying insects, I think. What kind of animal lays an egg like that?

[image]